# What Is The Metal "Wing" Connected To My Lower Strut Mount Mazda Protege 2002?

Tags: suspension, mazda, struts, stuck-bolt, protege

Connected to the lower strut mount of my Mazda Protege 2002 is a "wing" which leads away with a size 14mm bolt in it. I have been trying to loosen the rusted bolt, but I can't get it loose. I am wondering what the function of the connected system is and the impact if I have to cut the strut loose instead (and thus can't reconnect this system).

I've circled the bolt in red.

[image: Mystery Bolt]

I have found diagrams that show this part, but no labels are included for what this system may be. I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

It is the drop link that connects to the anti-roll bar.

When you go around corners, the car will naturally lean in the opposite direction to the turn.  The anti-roll bar limits the amount the car leans.  Leaving this disconnected will seriously affect handling and could cause an accident.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a stabilizer bar link. Hard to tell for sure due to the fact that the image is so small. I had to zoom the image 300% to make it out. If you take a more closer picture focusing the part in question then I can confirm it. It is a component of your suspension system.